# How can I get information about the artists if it was changed after certain date?

Tags: freebase, mql

I can get the artists that were added after 2014-10

```
[{
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "timestamp": null,
  "timestamp>=": "2014-10"
}]
```

But how can I choose those ones who were added before but information about them has been changed since 2014-10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the reflection capabilities to query the creation date of individual links.  See the [Links, Reflection, and History](https://developers.google.com/freebase/mql/ch03#links) section of the MQL manual.